# Xamarin Forms PCL HttpClient throwing unhandled exception on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using System.Net.Http.HttpClient directly in the Xamarin.Forms PCL. While it runs absolutely fine on Windows Phone, on Android it throws an unhandled exception on the GetAsync line.

Is there something platform specific I'm missing?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(Constants.ProjectsUri); // this breaks
```

Comment: What's the actual exception?

Comment: Beware!!! Android 5 has tons of bugs, if you are testing it with a lollipop device, try to run it as release instead of debug.

Comment: in stead of using await try .Result this has changed the behavior of my code sometimes

Comment: Nooooooooo don't listen to @MarioGalván. Never, ever, call `.Result`, you are introducing deadlocks which you don't want. Take a look at ModernHttpClient and see if it helps you fix your issue. It would help a lot if you provided the entire exception.

Comment: I have the same issue, that happens when there is a limited connectivity with the server (e.g. timeout, airplane mode). There is also a related issue in Xamarin Insights (update it if you use it) because of a bug in Mono. Did you find another solution?

Answer (score 1):

## Use the Native Android Client Handler

In the Android Build Settings, set `HttpClient Implementation` to use `AndroidClientHandler`.

[Link to Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/#Xamarin.Android)

> The AndroidClientHandler class was introduced in Xamarin.Android 6.1 to provide TLS 1.2 support to Xamarin.Android applications. This class uses the native java.net.URLConnection for all HTTP connections, allowing an HttpClient instance to use any network and encryption protocols available to Android.

[image]